# $.ajax() call to MSFT MVC failing in ISP, works locally

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The following JQuery $.ajax() call in a .js file works locally, but not when I deploy to my ISP.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Services/GetActivePatient',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (pt) {
        Alert(pt);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Error loading active patient' + 'XHR:' + xhr + ' OPTIONS:' + ajaxOptions + ' ERROR:' + thrownError);
    }
});
```

My routes are:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "aspx",
     "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
     new { action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

The difference w/ the ISP is the application/site is located in a subfolder (/ipd) that is enabled as an application in IIS6.

In this call I'm getting a "404 Page Not Found" error when I view the response in Firebug.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify the $.ajax() call is using JQuery in a .js file.

Comment: eu-ge-ne's answer below led to some research and the problem is that "/ipd" is being prefixed to all calls to the server since the site is located in the /ipd child folder. Apparently, even though the /ipd folder is marked as an application the $.ajax() call is going to the root of the site.

Changing the url to "/ipd/services.aspx/GetActivePatient" works. Rather than implement this workaround for all the calls I may instead try to move the site to the root(/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
url: 'Services/GetActivePatient',
```

to

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("GetActivePatient", "Services") %>',

// returns /ipd/Services/GetActivePatient on the ISP
// and /Services/GetActivePatient on local server
```

**UPDATED:**

If you have separate js file then use something like this in your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Services_GetActivePatient_Url = '<%= Url.Action("GetActivePatient", "Services") %>';
</script>
```

and then in js:

```
url: Services_GetActivePatient_Url,
```

Also look at [Stephen Walther - ASP.NET MVC Tip #45 – Use Client View Data](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/10/08/asp-net-mvc-tip-45-use-client-view-data.aspx)

Comment: This url definition is part of a JQuery $.ajax() call in a .js file so I don't believe server side scripts <% ... %> will be processed.